# Find $z$ values for the standard normal variable

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

Find the following z values for the standard normal variable Z. I got all the answers but B and I am pretty sure I'm right and the answer in the back of the book is wrong.Can you verify?

a.    P(Z ≤ z) = 0.1010   =-1.28

b.    P(z ≤ Z ≤ 0) = 0.1456     =-1.06 It says I am wrong though

c.    P(Z > z ) = 0.8186   =-.91

d.    P(0.29 ≤ Z ≤ z) = 0.3513  =1.81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you write $\Pr(Z\le z) = 0.1010 = -1.28$, that is certainly *not* correct since $0.1010$ is not equal to $-1.28$.  I presume you meant that if $\Pr(Z\le z)=0.1010$ then $z=-1.28$, which is correct up to rounding error.  The same thing applies to your other examples.  Don't do it that way.  Math professors look at assignments where things like that are written and they think are, to put it politely, deficient in understanding.

I'm getting $$\Pr(Z\le -1.055493)=0.1456$$ which is numerically close to what you have but it implies that $$\Pr(-1.055493\le Z\le 0) = 0.5-0.1456 = 0.0544.$$  Similar considerations affect your other answers.

Comment: I plugged that into my homework online and it still says that I am wrong. I put that it is equal to =-1.06 because it says to round to two decimal points. How I wrote the problem is how it is written on the homework and we enter an answer and hit enter and it says if we are right or wrong.

Comment: Please: Read my answer.  You are indeed wrong.  If you have $\Pr(z \le Z \le 0) = 0.1456$, then that implies $\Pr(Z\le z)=0.5-0.1456 = 0.3544$, which imples $z=-0.3734682$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that P(-1.06 < Z < 0) = .1456?
Can't be right. Suggest you draw a sketch.
The answer to P(-1.06 < Z < 0) is about .36.
Under a normal curve, about 68% of the area is between -1 and +1; 34%
on each side of 0. That leaves about 16% for each of the tails
(one to the left of -1, the other to the right of +1).

Comment: And I agree with the comment to use the equal sign ONLY between two things that are equal. Bad idea to use = as shorthand for "...and the answer is:". The computer can't see your work, but maybe your instructor can see it on the next test.

Comment: Note that about .36 and .1456 is about 0.5, meaning you can probably guess the error.